# Python example code to generate the most basic and simple typeform Form using a POST API?

Tags: python, api, typeform

I'm looking for a python code that uses the [POST] https://api.typeform.com/forms API to create a new form on Typeform

```
s = requests.post("https://api.typeform.com/forms", headers={"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)}, data=json.dumps(js2))
```

The problem I am encountering is in creating the json for the post request that contains the form details.
I'm looking for a very basic example without any welcome or thankyou screens, logics, jumps etc.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum you need to create a typeform via API is just the title of a form.

Like this:

```json
{
    "title": "My awesome form"
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the reply, I also wanted to add a few fields. Any field-type will do. Can you tell me how to make the dict for a typeform with two short-text fields with names "question1" and "question2" ?